# validate unix timstamp in controller by laravel validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

is there anyway to validate incoming unixtime's parameter to server and compare that second one is greather that first one by laravel validation? 
my code only validate date format

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'start_date'    => 'required|date',
            'end_date'   => 'required|date|after_or_equal:start_date',

        ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A timestamp is a number and can be anything between `0` and `2147483647`. That's all you can validate. (And of course that one is bigger than the other.)

So, you could do the following:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'start_date' => 'required|numeric',
    'end_date' => 'required|numeric|gte:start_date',
]);
```

- [`numeric`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-numeric) will make sure the input is a number
- [`gte`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-gte) checks if the value is greater than or equal to another number.

Comment: Who said it can't be [greater than a 32-bit integer](https://onlinephp.io/c/ded02)?